# If value of an input field = Sweden require a checkbox to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering on how i should solve this via JavaScript, I'm trying to make the checkbox field with the id="needs-confirm-sweden" to be required just if the word "Sweden" is inserted into the input country field. Any ideas on how I'm able to pull that off ?.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" value="" id="country" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="needs-confirm-sweden" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks, really appreciate any help on this

Comment: please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Vad har du provat? (from sweden: what have you tried?)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like,

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    if(!$('#needs-confirm-sweden').prop("checked")&&$('#country').val().trim() === 'Sweden') {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Please confirm the checkbox!'); 
     }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/X6wJM/10/)

Comment: You still need to do it on submit and preventDefault - I added it for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

```
if($('#country').val() == 'Sweden') { // if value is sweden
  if(!$('#needs-confirm-sweden').is(':checked') { // and checkbox is not checked
   alert('Please confirm the checkbox!'); // alert him, or not and so on!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#country').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Sweden" || $(this).val() == "sweden") {
        $("#needs-confirm-sweden").prop("required",true);
    } else {
        $("#needs-confirm-sweden").removeProp("required")
});
```

Comment: That is very cumbersome - why not $("#needs-confirm-sweden").prop("required", $(this).val().toLowerCase() == "sweden")

Comment: Good call, that's a more succinct way to put it, I won't edit the answer and steal your idea :)

Answer (score 0):

i see it took me to long to write this.. many posts now :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){

        if($('#country').val() == 'sweden')
        {
             if($('#needs-confirm-sweden').is(':checked'))
             {
                  alert('OK, you from sweden. fire event!');   
             }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('sorry, you have to confirm first');
            }
        }
        else
        {
              alert('you are from somewere, just fire the event');   
        }
    });
});
```

shorter version

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        if($('#country').val() == 'sweden')
        {
             if(!$('#needs-confirm-sweden').is(':checked'))
             {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  alert('sorry, you have to confirm first');  
             }
        }
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aSHTX/)**

guess version of Pranav Ram is a lil shorter :)

Comment: 1) the form will never submit 2) alerts no matter what

Comment: sure it alerts all the time.. its to see whats the state! ans why shoud the form never submit ? of corse you have to but something in there..